# Close userform with escape button

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 questions.

1. When I pressed <kbd>esc</kbd> button then close `Userform1`
2. When I input `open` in `TextBox1` then `Userform2` should show. Also clear `TextBox1` in `Userform1` automatically.

I have tried the below code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    If textbox1.value = "open" then
        userform2.show
        textbox1.value =""
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 32):

1. Insert a new Command Button
2. Switch its Cancel property to True
3. You May Name it as cmdClose
4. Add next code:

   ```
   Private Sub cmdClose_Click()

       Unload Me

   End Sub
   ```

5.Set height and widht of the button to 0

that's it

Comment: Make sure, that the new button is the only button with property Cancel set to True.

Comment: Consider also setting this button's `TabStop` property to `False` to remove the button from the keyboard's Tab cycle.

Comment: I have no idea why this method should work but it does. :-) I add comments to the main answer.

Answer (score 22):

> Close userform1 with <kbd>Esc</kbd>

If you don't have any controls on userform then simply use this code

```
Private Sub UserForm_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    If KeyAscii = 27 Then Unload Me
End Sub
```

If you have say a TextBox and a Command Button then use this

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    CommandButton1.Cancel = True
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    If KeyAscii = 27 Then Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    If KeyAscii = 27 Then Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

If you have any other control that can take focus then you will have to use the `KeyPress` event of that control like I did for `TextBox`

> when I input "open" to textbox1 then userform2 showed also clear textbox1 in userform1 automatically.

`KeyPress` will capture only one key. Use the `Change` event to compare what is there in the textbox.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If LCase(TextBox1.Value) = "open" Then
        TextBox1.Value = ""
        UserForm2.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this without creating the KeyPress sub for every button that can take focus? I have a userform with quite a few controls on it and I'd like to be able to use Esc to unload the form at any point.

Comment: Sorry I missed this comment... Yes create a control array. I have covered it on my [website](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/) as well as stackoverflow.

Comment: For some reason, nothing happens when I press the `Esc` key. Any suggestions?!

Comment: Which all controls do you have in the userform? @KarthickGanesan

Comment: @SiddharthRout, a couple of labels and a Frame.

Comment: @KarthickGanesan Have you put `If KeyAscii = 27 Then Unload Me` in `Private Sub Frame1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)` as well? Change `Frame1` to the relevant frame

Comment: Yikes, I missed that. Now it works! Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

if you have a button the closes the form, just set the (Cancel) *property* to *True* and that will fire the cancel button on (Esc).. 
Cheers.

Comment: Can you give an example if the button property is not Cancel?