# how to keep setfocus in textbox - vba excel

Tags: vba, excel, setfocus

I'm new in VBA, first I have a `userform`, `textbox1` and a `commandbutton1`. I have problem when I enter or press `Tab` in `textbox1` , I want textbox1 still in `setfocus` but it clicked `commandbutton1`.

I have code below:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        TextBox1.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

and what's VBA code to close userform1 when I press "F4" on keyboard?
thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Change you code from

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        TextBox1.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

to

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
ByVal Shift As Integer)
    '~~> 13 is for Enter, 9 is for Tab
    If KeyCode = 13 Or KeyCode = 9 Then
        KeyCode = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

> and what's VBA code to close userform1 when I press "F4" on keyboard

See [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240677/close-userform-with-escape-button/20241165#20241165). This thread is for <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. Change it for <kbd>F4</kbd>

LOL. It is one of your threads.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need to do, you might not need any code; try setting the text box's TabKeyBehavior property to True.  If you do that, the Tab keystroke gets entered as text rather than moving focus to the next control on the form.

You can do the same thing with the text control's EnterKeyBehavior property.